# Runtime Error 424 when embedding MapInfo map in Access form

Tags: mapinfo

I'm kind of new to VB and DAO so please bear with me on this! I'm not sure if this belongs in gis.se or stackoverflow.

I am trying to embed a simple MapInfo map in an Access form based on 
the code provided in the MapInfo user guide. It seems I've fallen at 
the first hurdle. So far I have this:

```
Dim mi As Object 
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer) 
    Set mi = CreateObject("MapInfo.Application") 
    MsgBox (mi) 
    mi.do "Set Application Window " & Form1.Hwnd 
    mi.do "Set Next Document Parent " & Form1.Hwnd & " Style 1" 
    mi.do "Open Table ""World"" Interactive Map From World" 
    mi.RunMenuCommand 1702 
    mi.do "Create Menu ""MapperShortcut"" ID 17 As ""(-"" " 
End Sub
```

I am getting runtime error 424 "object required" on this line:

`mi.do "Set Application Window " & Form1.Hwnd`

The MsgBox outputs "MapInfo Professional" which leads me to believe 
that the CreateObject command has worked successfully. 
However if I comment out the problem line I get the same error on the 
next line. Therefore I assume that the mi variable isn't correctly set 
up.

Can anybody shed any light on this?

Are there any good resources on line for MapInfo integrated mapping?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added the MapInfo reference in the VBA window in Access? Go to Tools > References. It should be called something like MapInfo x.xx OLE Automation Type Library (where x.xx is the version number of MapInfo)?

Comment: Yes I've done that. It doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: What else do you have ticked in the References dialog?

Comment: Visual basic for Applications, MS Access 11.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, MS DAO 3.6 Object Library and MS ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer on the [MapInfo Google Group](https://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l/browse_thread/thread/cfd2b129c07b693c?hl=en):

> I just tested this myself and got the same error. Then I noticed that 
>   under the MS Access Class Objects list (usually top left pane in the 
>   Visual Basic window) my 'Form1' was actually called 'Form_Form1'. Try 
>   using that instead; worked for me!
>   HTH, 
>   Tom Bacon